# TyperError: i is not a function (FireBug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>View Initialization</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqyery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script>

    SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                console.log("View is initialized");
            }
    });

    var search_view = new SearchView();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug is showing me following error:

> TypeError: i is not a function

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: src="js/jqyery.js" -> Is that a copy and paste failure? Btw: In html5 doctype you can leave out the `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: Proper     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqyery.js"></script> to     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> ....a spelling mistake can do much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a syntax error. You need to replace:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqyery.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Note the spelling mistake in the first `<script>` has been replaced (jqyery).